# h:link in JSF gets called automatically

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, el

I am creating a user authentification in JSF2, and my header displayed on every page contains this:

```
<c:if test="#{user.loggedIn}">
    <li><h:link value="Log out" outcome="#{user.logout}"/></li>
</c:if>
```

*User* refers to the userBean, and *logout()* simply invalidates the session, and issues a redirect to the login page. So when the user logs in, *user.loggedIn* becomes true, and logout link gets displayed, but it somehow immediately gets called, and the user is immediately logged out.

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening? I thought of using *h:commandLink*, but it requires a form, and I'm trying to avoid it.

**Edit:**
I copied the wrong code... just my luck after spending an hour figuring out why the user cannot login. You can look at the previous revision to see miscopied code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>That can happen when the JSF tags are not recognized and parsed as such and it effectively get rendered as plain text wherein all EL expressions are evaluated as value expressions. It would in your case basically print the returned value of `#{user.logout()}`. But while EL does that, the method's logic is of course invoked.</strike>

If you remove the `action` attribute and open the page in browser and do a *View Source*, then you'll see an unparsed `<h:commandLink>` tag instead of the generated HTML `<a>` element.

Make sure that you have the `h:` XML namespace definied on the right URI in the root tag of the view file.

```
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
```

---

**Update**: the `<h:link>` isn't intented to invoke bean actions. It's intented as a pure GET link. The `outcome` is [per specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) evaluated as a value expression, not as a method expression. The `outcome` must represent a view ID where the link has to navigate to. When the EL evaluates your method as a value expression, it's of course immediately invoked. Just keep using `<h:commandLink>` in combination with a redirect. Additional advantage is that this isn't bookmarkable nor searchbot-crawlable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've copied the wrong code (one that I used while experimenting with a solution). See the edit above.

Comment: The `<h:link>` cannot invoke bean actions. It's purely a GET link for page-to-page naviation. The `outcome` is by specification evaluated as a value expression. Just use `<h:commandLink>` combinied with a redirect. Additional advantage is that it isn't bookmarkable nor searchbot-crawlable.

Comment: You're welcome. In the future questions please don't be so careless with providing code :)

Answer (score -1):

This is the example from jsfToolbox:

```
<h:commandLink id="link1" 
               value="#{bundle.checkoutLabel}" 
               action="#{shoppingCartBean.checkout}" />
```

Get rid of your parens at the end of logout.

Comment: I get a server error: "The class 'project.UserBean' does not have the property 'logout'." Should I do something special with the method inside the bean?

Comment: This only confirms my answer more. EL is evaluating it as a value expression and without the parentheses it is then looking for a `getLogout()` method which doesn't exist.